# ¿Cómo se puede reproducir un video en python?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, ipython

Tengo un script en el que intento reproducir un video que tengo en una *carpeta local*. Estuve viendo muchas formas de realizarlo, se me esta complicando. Estoy usando `Jupyter Notebook` y `windows` para esto.

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
>>3.7.1
```

*intento 1 :*

```
import io
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML

encoded = base64.b64encode(video)
HTML(data='''<video alt="test" controls>
                <source src="data:video/mpg;base64,{0}" type="video/mpg" />
             </video>'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii')))
```

la salida es un reproductor todo en negro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Intento 2:*

```
from IPython.display import Video
filename='test.mpg'
Video(filename)
```

En el intento 2 obtengo la misma salida que en el intento 1.

*Intento 3:*

```
%%HTML
<div align="middle">
<video width="80%" controls>
      <source src="test.mpg" type="video/mpg">
</video></div>
```

La salida de este intento, es igual que las demás salidas.

También intente con otros videos con otros formatos, y tuve la misma salida.

Comment: Quizás el _codec_ con que está codificado el vídeo no es soportado por el navegador. Comprueba que sea mp4 (H.264) o webm. Por otro lado, la ruta al archivo de vídeo debe ser relativa a la carpeta desde la que has lanzado jupyter notebook.